# Could not find the source association(s) :followed in model Relationship.

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am following Michael Hartl's rails book and am getting the following error message:

```
ActiveRecord::HasManyThroughSourceAssociationNotFoundError: Could not find the source association(s) :follower in model Relationship. Try 'has_many :following, :through => :active_relationships, :source => <name>'. Is it one of ?
```

when calling `michael.follower` (where `michael` is a user object).

Here are the associations:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :active_relationships, class_name:  "Relationship",
                                      foreign_key: "follower_id",
                                      dependent:   :destroy

    has_many :passive_relationships, class_name: "Relationship",
                                     foreign_key: "followed_id",
                                     dependent: :destroy

    has_many :following, :through => :active_relationships, source: :follower
    has_many :followers, :through => :passive_relationships, source: :followed

end


class Relationship < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :follower, class_name: "User", foreign_key: "follower_id"
    belongs_to :followed, class_name: "User", foregin_key: "followed_id"

    validates :follower_id, presence: true
    validates :followed_id, presence: true
end
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you have many-to-many relation between User and Relationship models through relationship-model (I'm sorry for tautology).

I suggest to change

```
has_many :following, :through => :active_relationships, source: :follower
has_many :followers, :through => :passive_relationships, source: :followed
```

to

```
has_many :following, :through => :active_relationships, class_name: "User"
has_many :followers, :through => :passive_relationships, class_name: "User"
```